# Can you help me make a countdown and the button get visible

Tags: javascript, html

I searched every topic related count down but could not find a solution
I need to add  count down timer before the Close button gets visible.
Here is the code i have and need the Close text / button to be visible after a timer of 10 seconds is finished while count down goes a text Please Wait for x seconds to show.

Please help me add a timer count down  before close button shows to visitors.

```
<div align="center" id="sticky_bar">

<div id="sticky_bar_logo">
<div style="padding-left:5%;width:50%;float:left;text-align:left;">
<a href="#%site_url%#/" target="_blank" style="text-decoration:none; color:#FFFFFF;">#%site_title%#</a>
</div>
<div style="padding-right:5%;width:35%;float:right;text-align:right;">

<a href="#" onclick="document.getElementById('sticky_bar').style.display='none';" style="color:#FFFFFF;text-decoration:none; ">CLOSE</a>
</div>
</div>
<div id="sticky_bar_ad">#%ad1%#</div>
</div>
```

Comment: Where is your attempt?  You claim to have searched for information, and there are *many* examples of countdown timers for JavaScript to be found in even a cursory Google search.  As well as examples to show/hide an element.  In your research, what have you found?  What attempt did you make?  In what way does that attempt not work as expected?

Comment: I am sorry i have missed out :( i checked and solved the problem thank you so much

Answer (score 0):

HTML Part:

```
<div align="center" id="sticky_bar">

<div id="sticky_bar_logo">
<div style="padding-left:5%;width:50%;float:left;text-align:left;">
<a href="#%site_url%#/" target="_blank" style="text-decoration:none; color:#FFFFFF;">#%site_title%#</a>
</div>
<div style="padding-right:5%;width:35%;float:right;text-align:right;">

<a href="#" onclick="document.getElementById('sticky_bar').style.display='none';" style="color:#FFFFFF;text-decoration:none; " id="closeBtn">CLOSE</a>
</div>
</div>
<div id="sticky_bar_ad">#%ad1%#</div>
</div>
```

JavaScript Part:

```
 setTimeout(function(){ //function will be executed after 10 seconds       
    document.getElementById("closeBtn").style.display="block"; //will show the button
    }, 10*1000);
```

Explanation:

The `setTimeout()` method is inbuilt & calls a function or evaluates an expression after a specified number of milliseconds.

`document.getElementById("closeBtn").style` is used to access styling of an element with id `closeBtn` (i.e the CLOSE button)

Comment: No explanation about this code? How will the OP understand what you did? What the `setTimeout()` function does?

Comment: Explanation has been added. Thanks.

Comment: Not working at all my friend

Comment: Are you sure you added that Id for button?